# How to check if an item exists in a string List and if it exists, get its index

Tags: c#, winforms, list, linq

To get the index we can use 
    `int index = myList.FindIndex(a => a.StartsWith("string_to_search"));` when we are sure the string exists in `myList`.

But how to check if it is present in the List and get its index if it is present? For the time being, I am using the following code.

```
int ii=0;
foreach (var item in myList){
    if (item == "string_to_search")
        Console.WriteLine("Found at index: " + ii);
    // index is ii
    ii++;
}
```

Is there any better way to do this ?

Comment: "Is there any better way to do this" - yes use a dictionary it'll be way faster, if you care about performance

Comment: @MIKE Did you mean a `HashSet`?  because there is no need for a key-value dictionary when there's only values.  Also both wouldn't work if the order of the list is important.

Comment: @juharr the value would be the order, depends on his use case if a dictionary would work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `IndexOf` method to find index of item in list. This method returns -1 in case item does not exist in the list.

```
var itemIndex = myList.IndexOf("string_to_search")
```

Comment: Might want to mention that -1 means it wasn't found; otherwise, it looks like you only answer half the question.

Comment: Is there any significant (performance) difference between `IndexOf()` and `FindIndex()`? Both return -1 when string is not found in a list. Which one should be used ?

Comment: @Thundrstorm Kindly refere this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31965778/efficiency-of-listt-indexof-versus-listt-findindex.